# Knockout Observable and Google Chrome Auto-Fill issue

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, knockout.js

Basically, I have a login button on a login form that works fine with jQuery 1.8.3 (I've tried 1.9.0) and Knockout 2.2.1 observables and a binding to enable/disable the login button.

The enable button is disabled when the computed function sees that there is a missing username OR password.

However, the problem arises when Google Chrome (24.0.1312.56 m) autofills the textbox a few moments after the page loads.  The viewmodel and computed observable doesn't detect when Chrome updates the textbox so the button stays disabled.

I made a basic jsfiddle.  I have no clue how to make the jsfiddle autofill to show this problem :)  You'll just have to trust me.

Javascript/ViewModel

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    var loginViewModel = function() {

        var self=this;
        self.loginName = ko.observable("");
        self.loginPass = ko.observable("");

        self.loginInfoValid = ko.computed(function() {

            if (self.loginName().length > 0 && self.loginPass().length > 0) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }

        });

    };

    ko.applyBindings(new loginViewModel());     
});
```

HTML

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: loginName, valueUpdate:'afterkeydown'"><br>
<input type="text" data-bind="value: loginPass, valueUpdate:'afterkeydown'"><br>
<span data-bind="text: loginName"></span><br>
<button data-bind="enable: loginInfoValid">Login</button>
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vW6Xy/1/

Thank you!!

Comment: Is turning off autocomplete an option?

Comment: Steven - Preferably not on this login form.  I will keep that in mind for other annoying inputs.  Thanks!

Comment: For the record, the same problem happened to me on Chrome 35 on my phone. It did not occur on Chrome 34 on a computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either

- bind a `change` event handler to the text object and manually call the `self.loginInfoValid` method, or
- use `setTimeout` to wait a short time and manually call the `self.loginInfoValid` method.

If the `change` event is thrown when Chrom autofills, that would be my preferred solution of the two.

Comment: `change` doesn't appear to be fired when Chrome autofills. It seems setTimeout is the "way to hack it"

Comment: I actually ended up sending a keyup/keydown event using setTimeout.  The hack felt so wrong and I'd like to find a better way to do it.  I was a bit hesitant on posting a knockout bug because I wasn't sure if I misread the documentation.

Comment: Thank you Jeff.  Again, I'm not sure if this is considered a bug.

Answer (score 1):

Found a nice unobtrusive way of doing it, for example:

```
var emailInput = $('#email');
var passwordInput = $('#password');

emailInput.on('blur', function () { passwordInput.trigger('change'); });
```

So when you lose focus over the email/user input, it will trigger the change event on the password input causing password property on the viewmodel to be updated.

Comment: Perhaps a more robust solution is to trigger 'change' on submitting the form.